# Rotated div creates whitespace

Tags: css, removing-whitespace

I see this was asked and answered before, but this being slightly more complex solution, perhaps community could help me.

I have this dial with div elements that form an arc. Unfortunately, as you can see below that creates a lot of unwanted whitespace. How can I remove it?

[image: CSS rotated element creates whitespace]

Comment: overflow hidden on a parent. C'mon. You can do it!

Comment: Thanks for support! I've set parent to 100px, overflow hidden. Then I've changed child div's from 100% height to 200px.

Comment: Well done! That was easy. (or instead of `200px` you could've used `200%` (twice the 100px))